# Why do I get floating point exception 8?

Tags: c, greatest-common-divisor

For my Intro. to programming exam review I was asked to write a program which uses a function to calculate the gcd of a set of numbers. I wrote the following code, which sometimes seems to work fine, but others returns Floating Point Exception 8. I was hoping someone could shed some light.

I complied it using `clang gcd.c -o gcd` on the mac terminal using macOS High Sierra and the numbers that return the FP error were `5372 18960 -230048 1185 16486`

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gcd(int a, int b){
    if((a==0) || (b==0)){
        return 0;
    }else{
        if( a % b == 0 ){
            return b;
        }else{
            if ( b % a == 0 ){
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
    while( (a != 0) && (b != 0) ){
        if (abs(a)>abs(b)){
            a = abs(a) % abs(b);
        }
        if(b>a){
            b = abs(b) % abs(a);
        }
    }
    if (a == 0){
        return b;
    }else{
        return a;
        }
}

int main(void){
    int n;
    printf("Please enter the number of integers in your array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n];

    printf("Please enter the numbers in your arrray:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); ++i){
            a[i] = gcd(a[i], a[i+1]); 
    }

    printf("The gcd of the %d numbers is %d .\n", n, a[n-2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= n;` Here we go again. Suppose n==2. How many numbers are there? What is the index of the first number? What is the index of the last number? What are the natural numbers `<=2`?

Comment: @n.m Nice catch. But even so, It's pretty wild that an FP error is thrown by a program with no FP operations. Could it be an interpreter that uses doubles to do int arithmetic or something weird like that? AlexD, you really need to include info on your environment with questions like this.

Comment: @Gene Undefined Behavior. Also `%` implies division.

Comment: @Gene division by zero usually causes an FP error, even when it's integral.

Comment: @n.m. I was using for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); ++i) But I got the error when I was using these specific numbers: 5372 18960 -230048 1185 16486.

Comment: @Gene I compiled on the mac terminal using macOS High Sierra, but I ran it on repl.it and I still got an exit error

Comment: Review this code `for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); ++i){
        a[i] = gcd(a[i], a[i-1]); 
    }`  What is `a[i-1]` on the first iteration?

Comment: I'd expect `for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); ++i){
        a[i+1] = gcd(a[i], a[i+1]); 
    }`

Comment: Note: `abs(INT_MIN)` is UB.  Unclear on the **need** of `abs()` in `gcd()`.

Comment: @chux Ok now I have  `for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); ++i){
  a[i] = gcd(a[i], a[i+1]); 
}`  But I still get the error. Also, I'm pretty new to programming, I'm sorry I'm not familiar with the terminology, but what is UB?

Comment: `UB` means undefined behavior

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: about the third iteration of this loop: `while( (a != 0) && (b != 0) )` in the function: `gcd()` the first `if()` results in 'a being set to 0 then the second `if()` is also executed, resulting in a divide by 0.  I.E. the logic is wrong.  Suggest checking if 'a' is still not 0 before executing the second 'if()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like couple of mistakes in your code for finding GCD.

You should update the value of `a[i+1]` in your for loop instead of `a[i]`. And the GCD will be `a[n-1]`th element after this change. As you iterate over the loop `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` will be original (input) values in your case. So if everything else works fine, your result will be GCD of last two elements of the array (`a[n-2]`, `a[n-1]`).

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); ++i) {
    a[i+1] = gcd(a[i], a[i+1]); 
}
```

In the `while` loop of `gcd()`, you need to make the following changes. Check for `a==b` conditionality and change the two `if` conditions to `if-else` conditions. In case `b` is a factor of `a`, `a` becomes `0` in your first `if` condition. Then in the second condition, you are doing `% 0` which is throwing the error.

```
while( (a != 0) && (b != 0) ){
    if (abs(a)>=abs(b){
        a = abs(a) % abs(b);
    }
    else if(abs(b)>abs(a)){
        b = abs(b) % abs(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although @u__ said it earlier, I'm an idiot and didn't realize I was missing the else statement until you said it. +1 to both though thank you so much.

Comment: `else if(abs(b)>abs(a)){` can certainly be simplified to `else {`.

Answer (score 2):

first impression in the `while` loop below

```
while( (a != 0) && (b != 0) ){
    if (abs(a)>abs(b)){
        a = abs(a) % abs(b); // value of a is altered and reused 
    }
    if(b>a){
        b = abs(b) % abs(a);  // here <-- and could very well be a 0
    }
}
```

---

on a completely different note your could remove `else {}` blocks, if you could take a moment and see that `else` blocks are not really adding any value because there is a `return` in `if`

```
int gcd(int a, int b){

    /** sanity checks */
    if((a==0) || (b==0))
        return 0;

    /* few more obvious checks */
     if( a % b == 0 )
        return b;
     if( b % a == 0 )
        return a;

    /* Real Logic */
     while( (a != 0) && (b != 0) ){
        if (abs(a)>abs(b)){
            a = abs(a) % abs(b);
        }
        else if(abs(b) > abs(a) ){
            b = abs(b) % abs(a);
        }
    }

    /* Final results */
    return (a == 0) ? b : a;
}
```